# Read Json with coffee script

Tags: json, coffeescript

After having stored a java List in json url i got the following json in this url /formFields

```html
["[DATE]","[VOTRE NOM DE COMPAGNIE]","[TYPE DE SOCIETE]","[LOI CONSTITUTIVE/LOI RELATIVE]","[ADRESSE COMPLETE]","[NOM SECOND CONSTITUANT]","[TYPE DE SOCIETE]","[LOI CONSTITUTIVE/LOI RELATIVE]","[ADRESSE COMPLETE]"]
```

I tried and tried but i don't achieve to read this Json url with this coffee script :

```
$ ->
  $.get "/formFields", (formFields) ->
    $.each formFields, (index, field) ->
      $("#formFields").append $("field")
```

please help

Comment: Could it be that you need to `JSON.parse(formFields)` your data?

Comment: What Content-Type is the server using with the response? What specifically is in `formFields`?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I coding an app with play framework. My app extract data from a file and store it in java list. To display the list content in my web page, i choose to create a json from my list and to read it with coffee script (like in the play framework tutorial)

Comment: Can you answer @muistooshort's question? That would really help. It looks like you are using jQuery, check the documentation for `$.get()` here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: thx all for help.. i think content type is plain text. i'm checking your jquery tuto and json.parse and i'll let you know asap

Comment: Finaly i found a solution, my json wasn't well formatted. I changed to this : [{"id":"1","field":"[DATE]"},{"id":"2","field":"[VOTRE NOM DE COMPAGNIE]"},{"id":"3","field":"[TYPE DE SOCIETE]"},{"id":"4","field":"[LOI CONSTITUTIVE/LOI RELATIVE]"}]. And my Jquery now is  : $ ->
  $.get "/formFieldsss", (formFieldsss) ->
    $.each formFieldsss, (index, formField) ->
      $("#formFieldsss").append $("<tr>")
      $("#formFieldsss").append $("<td>").text formField.field
      $("#formFieldsss").append $("<td>").text formField.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found a solution, my json wasn't well formatted. I changed to this :

```
[{"id":"1","field":"[DATE]"},{"id":"2","field":"[VOTRE NOM DE COMPAGNIE]"},    {"id":"3","field":"[TYPE DE SOCIETE]"},{"id":"4","field":"[LOI CONSTITUTIVE/LOI RELATIVE]"}].
```

And my Jquery now is :

```
$ -> 
  $.get "/formFields", (formFields) -> 
    $.each formFields, (index, field) -> 
      $("#formFields").append $("<tr>") 
      $("#formFields").append $("<td>").text field.field
      $("#formFields").append $("<td>").text field.id
```